# RouterLink would not be clickable in a nav-bar with bootstrap and angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I have a nav-bar.

In this nav-bar i wanna scroll down, when the href is set with the # but when it would be set a routerLink, then I wanna go to this page:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">hFinder</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#cards">Cards</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#impressum">Impressum</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']">Start</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Link is in the top but I can't click it. The card and the impressum scroll down.

[image]

Here is the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SedcardComponent } from './sedcard/sedcard.component';
import { StartComponent } from './start/start.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: StartComponent },
    { path: 'sedcard/:id', component: SedcardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true} )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the console:

Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}

Router Event: RoutesRecognized
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
RoutesRecognized {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
GuardsCheckStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: ChildActivationStart
ChildActivationStart(path: '')
ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}

Router Event: ActivationStart
ActivationStart(path: '')
ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}

Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } , shouldActivate: true)
GuardsCheckEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}

Router Event: ResolveStart
ResolveStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
ResolveStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: ResolveEnd
ResolveEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
ResolveEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}

Router Event: ActivationEnd
ActivationEnd(path: '')
ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
Router Event: NavigationEnd
NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}

Router Event: Scroll
Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
Scroll {routerEvent: NavigationEnd, position: null, anchor: null}

Comment: Since you have `enableTracing: true`do you see any output in the console ?

Comment: I add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want fragmentation in angular.

When you use `href="#youcontent"`, It will redirect your page into particular url. Don't use it in your angular.

Use like this :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" (click)="moveToCard()">Cards</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add Template reference variable In your html.

```
<div #Test>
   <div>
       <p>You content </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Call this in your .ts file like this.

```
@ViewChild('test') public test : ElementRef;

public moveToCard():void {
    this.test.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
}
```

**Or Use This Method :**

.ts

```
changeFragment(value) {
    document.querySelector('#' + value).scrollIntoView({ behavior : 'smooth' });
};
```

.html

```
<p id="divA">
  <strong> This is the Div A </strong>.<br>
    <button (click)="changeFragment('divB')">Jump to Div B</button>
</p>

<p id="divB">
    <strong> This is the Div B </strong>.<br>
    <button (click)="changeFragment('divA')">Back to DivA</button>.
</p>
```

Comment: Mhm, it seems to hear logical :) I try it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @MiracleJohnson I have updated answer with one more solution.